# How can I create an animation showing how a circular sector deformed to a cone?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, animation

I want to create the following animation with Mathematica.

[image]

What is the simplest way to do so?

My first effort:

```
GenerateLines[a_, b_, r_, n_] :=
  Table[r {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], 0}, {\[Theta], a, b, (b - a)/
    n}];
basePts = GenerateLines[\[Pi]/6, 2 \[Pi] - \[Pi]/6, 3, 200];
peakPt = {{0, 0, 3}};
baseLine = Line@basePts;
slantedLines = Line /@ Tuples[{basePts, peakPt}];
Graphics3D[{baseLine, slantedLines}]
```

[image]

Comment: The wireframe can be removed with a textured surface as shown in [this site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64204/how-to-deform-a-2d-shape-to-make-a-3d-object).

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
ClearAll[cone, radius]

radius[h_] = r /. First@
    Solve[{Pi r Sqrt[r^2 + h^2] (1 + h )/2 == Pi /2, h > 0}, r, Reals];
radius[0] = 1;

cone[h_] := ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[θ] (1 - z) radius[h], Sin[θ] (1 - z) radius[h], h z},
   {θ, 0, Pi + h Pi}, {z, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> None, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#4&},
   Boxed -> False, 
   PlotRange -> 1.5 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> GrayLevel[.2], 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   Axes -> False];

axes = Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[Medium], 
    MapThread[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 1.4 #2}], Text[#, 1.5 #2]} &, 
     {{"X", "Y", "Z"}, IdentityMatrix[3]}]}];

Manipulate[Show[cone @ h, axes], {{h, 0, "height"}, 0, 1}]
```

[image: enter image]

Animation above produced using:

```
frames = Table[Show[cone @ h, axes], {h, 0, 1, .01}];

Export["animatecone.gif", frames, AnimationRepetitions -> ∞, DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

Comment: @KimJongUn, please see the updated version.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12):

[image]

```
ClearAll[draw];

draw[deg_, segmentsNumber_Integer, z_] :=
 With[{singleSegment = 
    Polygon@{{0, 0, z}, {1, 0, 0}, {Cos[deg Degree], Sin[deg Degree], 0}}},

  NestList[
   GeometricTransformation[#, 
     RotationTransform[deg Degree, {0, 0, 1}]] &, singleSegment, 
   segmentsNumber]]

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.5, 0, 0}}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.5, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.5}}], 
   Text["x", {1.6, 0, 0}], Text["y", {0, 1.6, 0}], 
   Text["z", {0, 0, 1.6}], Transparent, draw[10 + i*8, 19, i]}, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], {i, 0, 1}]
```

### Update

For removing axes moves, use `PlotRange` in `Graphics3D`:

```
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}
```

Comment: Excellent! Let me wait for a couple of hours or maybe days.

Comment: @KimJongUn I used [Snagit](https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html) to capture which also have a built-in gif converter.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

```
 Animate[
 r = Sqrt[1 - h^2];
 phi = Sqrt[2] Pi /r;
 pts = Table[r {Cos[p], Sin[p], 0}, {p, 0, phi, phi/10}];
 ptsc = Table[r {Cos[p], Sin[p], 0}, {p, 0, phi, phi/100}];
 Graphics3D[{Line[ptsc], Line[{#, {0, 0, h}}] & /@ pts, Red, 
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], Text["X", {1.1, 0, 0}], 
   Text["Y", {0, 1.1, 0}], Text["Z", {0, 0, 1.1}]}, Boxed -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
 , {h, 0, 1/Sqrt[2]}, TrackedSymbols -> h]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 5):

Just a start:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[Cone[{{0, 0, h}, {0, 0, 1}}]],
 {h, 0, 0.9}
 ]
```

[image]
[image]

And a bit more...

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{
   {Opacity[0.5], Cone[{{0, 0, h}, {0, 0, 1}}]},
   Line[{{1.25, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}],
   Line[{{0, 1.25, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}],
   Line[{{0, 0, 1.25}, {0, 0, 0}}]
   },
  Boxed -> False],
 {h, 0, 0.9}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: From a sector to a cone rather than from a circle to a cone. :-)

Answer (score 5):

At first we shrinking the boundary of sector to circle, keeping the arc length. That is `l*α==R*θ`

```
α = 0.8*2 π;
l = 4;
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[R*{Cos[s], Sin[s], 0} /.R->(l*α)/θ, {s, 0, θ}, PlotRange -> 4, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {θ, α, 2 π}]
```

[image]

Then we draw line from the shrinking curve to the vertex of the cone `{0,0,Sqrt[l^2 - R^2]}` so we keep the length of generatrix say `l`.

```
α = 0.8*2 π;
l = 4;
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[(1 - t)*(R*{Cos[s], Sin[s], 0}) + 
    t*{0, 0, Sqrt[l^2 - R^2]} /. R -> (l*α)/θ, {s, 
   0, θ}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> 4, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> 20, 
  Boxed -> False], {θ, α, 2 π, .2}]
```

[image]